# How long does it take to create mobile application for every single platform?

Tags: mobile, time, smartphone

1. What's the most diffucult mobile platform for development? IOS,
   Android, WP?
2. Which OS would take less time(if you're quite exprerienced)? And what's the most
       comfortable mobile OS for development?
3. If you have just a little coding skills, and you have to make an app
   as fast as possible, which OS is suitable more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to me , a slight difficult OS platform is Blackberry OS because of following reasons :

1. Various screen sizes/densities and button layouts.
2. Data connection.
       Yes, making a data connection is not trivial on BlackBerry. OS
       support. Currently foursquare supports OS 4.2.1 (OS  running on 4
       year old devices) and up.
3. Application distribution and updating.
       Foursquare currently makes 3 different builds to satisfy varying OS
       functionality and API features. Some companies go as far as making
       up to 7 or 8 seperate build, one for almost every OS level.

If you have less coding skills, you can start developing an App with Android OS.
There are numerous tools and tutorials which help you to learn Android development.